# Google Dataflow failed with status FAILED

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

When Submitting Job to Google Dataflow it gives the error "failed with status FAILED"

Any Idea?

```
Nov 16, 2016 6:25:34 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner run
INFO: Job finished with status FAILED
Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowJobExecutionException: Job 2016-11-16_08_25_02-3648727548396803107 failed with status FAILED
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:158)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:56)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:181)
    at com.kryptonz.proccess.UsersProfileDatastoreBatchView.main(UsersProfileDatastoreBatchView.java:67)
```

Comment: Please post the full console output of this job.

Comment: i do check please.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, we're investigating what may be the cause of these problems.

Comment: Thanks I try now it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there were some problems with the project configuration that have since been resolved. Sorry about the inconvenience!

Comment: I'm getting the same `DataflowJobExecutionException` in all the dataflow jobs across two of my projects. Can you please explain what needs to be changed in the project configuration?

Comment: Are you still having problems? Things should be properly configured now.

Comment: I'm getting this problem now, no detail in the error message. @BenChambers any ideas?

Comment: @OğuzYıldız could you provide Job IDs or other information to help us identify the problem?

Comment: Did some digging and found details :)

Comment: There was a problem refreshing your credentials. Please check:1. Dataflow API is enabled for your project.
2. There is a robot service account for your project:
service-[project number]@dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com should have access to your project. If this account does not appear in the permissions tab for yourproject, contact Dataflow support.

Comment: Is that sufficient for solving the problem? You may want to look at the Dataflow docs on [security and permissions](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/security-and-permissions). If not, a job ID would be necessary to dig deeper on our side.